# Remove "?id=" from dynamic URLs

Tags: django

I'm pretty new to django and i'm working on a website that needs a dynamic URL for a database table, and it all works fine, but i would like to know how to remove the "?id=" from the url, so rather than

> localhost:8000/dynamicurl/?id=XXXXX

The url becomes

> localhost:8000/dynamicurl/XXXXX

Instead

I did a fine amount of searching in the documentation and didn't find a lot, though it's pretty likely i missed something.

EDIT:
thanks everyone for helping, the simplest answer was to remove the object i was using to fetch the ID and just replace it for ID in evert instance,

so my url became

> url(r'^dynamicurl/(?P[0-9]+)/$', views.dynamicurl)

and my view became

> def dynamicurl(request, id):

i'm like very very new to django FYI

Comment: From the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#named-groups

Comment: And the tutorial. And every piece of introductory text ever written about Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can capture a variable in url definition in the apps urls.py file. It would look something like this:

```
url(r'^dynamicurl/(?P<id>[0-9]+)?$', dynamicurl, name = 'dynamicurl'),
```

then in your view function you receive that parameter:

```
def dynamicurl(request, id):
```

Comment: so i tried your solution and it didn't work, i think it's because of the way i made the view, which was to use idn =  dinamicurl.request.GET.get(id = idn) to find the object ID

Comment: def pickoff(request):
    idn = request.GET.get('id')
    if idn:
        p = Pickoff.objects.get(id=idn)

that's what it was prior to the change
and the url was
url(r'^pickoff/', views.pickoff)

Comment: You just need to change the view function's `def` statement to take the `idn` argument after `request`, and change the url string to have `?P<idn>` instead of `?P<id>`. Rest of your code should work as is after that. If you're still having issues you should post the full urls.py file and the full view function so that we can help.

Comment: i did the changes and now the server won't run, the console says 
NameError: name 'pickoff' is not defined

Comment: did you import the pickoff view function in urls.py?

Comment: i changed the url pattern from url(r'^pickoff/(?P<idn>[0-9]+)?$', pickoff, name = 'pickoff'),
 to url(r'^pickoff/(?P<idn>[0-9]+)?$', views.pickoff, name = 'pickoff') and it runs, but still no luck in getting in the URL

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about how to change your url inside the `urls`, I suggest you to use code that already answered above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41988051/6396981

But, if you talking about how to redirect `localhost:8000/dynamicurl/?id=XXXXX` to `localhost:8000/dynamicurl/XXXXX`, hope this usefull..

**1. `views.py`**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


class RedirectView(RedirectView):
    permanent = False

    def get_redirect_url(self):
        get_id = self.request.GET.get('id')
        if get_id is not None:
            return reverse('redirected_page', kwargs={'id': id})
        return reverse('origin_page')


def redirected_view(request, id):
    # your final view goes here...
    return HttpResponse("You're looking for id: %d." % id)
```

**2. `urls.py`**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from yourapp.views import views (RedirectView, redirected_view)


urlpatterns = [
    # first view the pool to doing redirection
    url(r'^pool/$', RedirectView.as_view(), name='origin_page'),

    # the final url
    url(r'^pool/(?P<id>[\d]+)/$', redirected_view, name='redirected_page'),
]
```